# WPF Databinding with nested collections does not update control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, collections

I have an `Objectmodel` with some nested Collections:

```
public class MainViewModel :  BaseViewModel
{
    private Dictionary<String, Diagram> _diagrams;

    public Dictionary<String, Diagram> Diagrams
    {
        get { return _diagrams; }
        set
        {
            _diagrams = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Diagrams");
        }
    }
```

}

Base Viewmodel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Inside `Diagram` there is a Collection of Curves:

```
public class Diagram
{
    private  ObservableCollection<DiagramCurve> curves;
    [JsonIgnoreAttribute]
    public ObservableCollection<DiagramCurve> Curves
    {
        get { return curves; }
    }

    public Diagram()
    {
        curves = new ObservableCollection<DiagramCurve>();
    }
}
```

I bind to an instance of `DiagramCanvas` in my Xaml like this:

```
    <wd:DiagramCanvas x:Name="diagramCanvas" 
                          Diagram ="{Binding Diagrams[Diagram1]}"  
                          Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                          Height="auto" Width="Auto"  
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          Margin="10"   
                          Background="{StaticResource DiagrambackgroundBrush }" />
```

which works fine if I assign the the Diagrams property of `MainView` a completely new Diagrams collection. But what I need is that the `DiagramCanvas` Control get's updated when the Curves Collection changes. But this does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to inherit `Diagram` from an 'ObservableCollection', but even this didn't help as in [ObservableCollection dependency property does not update when item in collection is deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362278/observablecollection-dependency-property-does-not-update-when-item-in-collection) explained.

As the DependencyProperty of my CustomControl `DiagramCanvas` binds to a value item of the Dictionary `MainViewModel.Diagrams` not to a property of a `Diagram` instance, no `OnPropertyChanged` event of the DependencyProperty of `DiagramCanvas`is fired, when properties of the `Diagram` instance change.

Only when a new value is assigned to the value item inside the Dictionary `MainViewModel.Diagrams`, this event gets fired, beacause this assigns a new value to the `DependencyProperty` of `DiagramCanvas`.

Therefore I have to subscribe to the events of the collection manually:.

```
public class DiagramCanvas : Canvas
{
  // Is called only when new Items get inserted info the Dictionary
  static void OnDiagramPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, 
                                     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  {
      DiagramCanvas THIS = (DiagramCanvas)obj;

      Diagram new_diagram = (Diagram)args.NewValue;
      Diagram old_diagram = (Diagram)args.NewValue;

      if (old_diagram != null)
      {
        // Unsubscribe from CollectionChanged on the old collection
        old_diagram.Curves.CollectionChanged -= THIS.OnCollectionChanged;
      }

      if (new_diagram != null)
      {
        // Subscribe to CollectionChanged on the new collection
        new_diagram.Curves.CollectionChanged += THIS.OnCollectionChanged;
      }
  }

  //Is called everytime the Curves collecion changes
  void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is on the `MainViewModel` `Diagrams` Property, and selecting the diagram corresponding to the "Diagram1" string. In your binding path, there is no mention of the `Curves` Property, so the binding won't update when the Curves throw a `CollectionChanged` Event. To prevent this, you could register to this event in your `MainViewModel`, and when it comes throw a `PropertyChanged` Event of the good diagram in your dictionary.

But... if I'm not mistaken, the .Net Dictionary doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, and I'm not sure the binding will update anyway. You should try and keep me informed.

Happy Coding,

Antoine

Comment: How would I register the Event in the 'MainViewModel'? I already ttied to use an ObservableDictionary Class for the Diagrams Collection, but this won't help as I don't change this collection.

Comment: Yes, in this case you should not register to the Diagrams Collection changed event, but to the Curves Collection changed event. A second thought : as you have also created your own control called DiagramCanvas, this control could be the one to register to the Curvers.CollectionChanged when it receive a Diagram. Just don't forget to unregister the event if the diagram changes afterwards or if the view is unloaded to avoid memoryleaks. You could also change your DiagramCanvas to provide a Curves DependencyProperty, instead of the Diagram. This way, all the event registration would be automatic.

Comment: Actually as you can see in my own answer DiagramCanvas now registers to the Curves.OnColletionChanged event. I need to Bind to the DiagramProperty, becaus my Control need more data from Diagram as only the curves.