# collection dependency properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, dependency-properties

I have a custom control that has a `DependencyProperty` of type `ObservableCollection` that is bound to an `observableCollection`:

```
<MyControl MyCollectionProperty = {Binding MyObservableCollection} ...
```

Problem is adding to `MyObservableCollection` does not update `MyCollectionProperty`.

I need to completly replace the `MyObservableCollection` to make it work e.g.

```
MyObservableCollection = null;
MyObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection(){...}
```

Is there a better way to deal with this?

*EDIT:*

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> Columns
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MyControl),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>(), OnChanged));
```

Comment: Would you post the definition of your dependency property? Could be something off in there...

Comment: Is your "MyControl" monitoring PropertyChanged or CollectionChanged and are you monitoring PropertyChanged on the objects within your observable collection?

Comment: yes there is a callback in the defintion and handler for CollectionChanged never gets fired. I don't see where listening for PropertyChanged on the items is relevent since we are talking about adding.

Comment: Can you post the OnChanged method? Btw it isn't a good idea to provide a defaultvalue for your dp. Every instance of the control will reference the same collection instance by default.

Comment: Ah.. good point about the default value. I could post the handler but its kind of irrelevant because it never gets called.

Comment: Similar problem asked and answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362278/observablecollection-dependency-property-does-not-update-when-item-in-collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a working example that may help.

In this example, the method OnChanged is called immediately, when the Add button is clicked "Changed" is written to the console.

The Control

```
public class MyControl : Control
{

    public ObservableCollection<string> ExtraColumns
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ExtraColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ExtraColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtraColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ExtraColumns", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MyControl),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>(), OnChanged));

    static void OnChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as MyControl).OnChanged();

    }

    void OnChanged()
    {
        if ( ExtraColumns != null )
            ExtraColumns.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ExtraColumns_CollectionChanged);
    }

    void ExtraColumns_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Changed");    
    }
}
```

The Window

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication18.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication18"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <StackPanel>
    <local:MyControl ExtraColumns="{Binding Extras}"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Add</Button>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Window Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _extras = new ObservableCollection<string>( );
    public ObservableCollection<string> Extras
    {
        get { return _extras; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _extras)
            {
                _extras = value;
            }
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Extras.Add("Additional");
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use code `new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>()` in registering dependency property. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970563%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for explanation

Comment: Doesn't this cause a problem where the underlying collection gets shared by all instances of MyControl?  According to this link you have to manually set a new collection in the constructor of MyControl to avoid this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970563%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 20):

In addition to what grantz has answered, I would suggest to declare the property with type `IEnumerable<string>` and check at runtime if the collection object implements the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668629.aspx) interface. This provides greater flexibility as to which concrete collection implementation may be used as property value. A user may then decide to have their own specialized implementation of an observable collection.

Note also that in the `ColumnsPropertyChanged` callback the `CollectionChanged` event handler is attached to the new collection, but also removed from the old one.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Columns", typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(MyControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, ColumnsPropertyChanged));

public IEnumerable<string> Columns
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
}

private static void ColumnsPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control= (MyControl)obj;
    var oldCollection = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    var newCollection = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

    if (oldCollection != null)
    {
        oldCollection.CollectionChanged -= control.ColumnsCollectionChanged;
    }

    if (newCollection != null)
    {
        newCollection.CollectionChanged += control.ColumnsCollectionChanged;
    }

    control.UpdateColumns();
}

private void ColumnsCollectionChanged(
    object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // optionally take e.Action into account
    UpdateColumns();
}

private void UpdateColumns()
{
    ...
}
```